# How do I unsubscribe from a lambda event that needs variables passing into it?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a custom control in WPF (MenuButton) and want to add a click event handler to a list of them. The event handler requires an integer to be passed into it, like so:

```
List<MenuButton> mbButtons;

private void SetUpButtons()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    foreach (MenuButton item in mbButtons)
    {
        SubscribeToClickEvent(item, r.Next(0, 11));
    }
}

private void SubscribeToClickEvent(MenuButton mb, int i)
{
    mb.Click += (sender, e) => MyClickEvent(sender, e, i);
}
```

But how do I then unsubscribe from the event for each button?

Comment: Note that `MenuButton` doesn't seem to be part of WPF...

Comment: @canton7 Indeed, you´re right. I missed the additional parameter. Otherwise OP could just use `mb.Click += MyClickEvent;`.

Comment: I think. If this method you're writing is internal to the custom control  you can just set mb.Click = null; Otherwise, you need  a reference to your original delegate. Maybe you should consider weak events if memory leaks are your primary concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it makes more sense to keep relevant data in button instance, and retrive it in event handler:

```
List<MenuButton> mbButtons;

private void SetUpButtons()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    foreach (MenuButton item in mbButtons)
    {
        item.Tag = r.Next(0, 11);
        item.Click += MyClickEvent;
    }
}

private void MyClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mb = (MenuButton)sender;
    int i = (int)mb.Tag;
}
```

then unsubscribe without any difficulties using known method name:

```
mb.Click -= MyClickEvent;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to store the delegate, and use it again to unsubscribe.

```
private RoutedEventHandler handler;

private void SubscribeToClickEvent(MenuButton mb, int i)
{
    handler = (sender, e) => MyClickEvent(sender, e, i);
    mb.Click += handler;
}

private void UnsubscribeFromClickEvent(MenuButton mb)
{
    mb.Click -= handler;
    handler = null;
}
```

Of course, add your own logic to handle the case where `SubscribeToClickEvent` is called more than once.

---

You edited your question to have an array of buttons, so here's an adjusted answer:

You will need to keep a list of delegate instances to remove:

```
private List<MenuButton> mbButtons;
private readonly List<(MenuButton button, RoutedEventHandler handler)> clickHandlers = new List<(MenuButton, RoutedEventHandler)>();

private void SetUpButtons()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    foreach (MenuButton item in mbButtons)
    {
        SubscribeToClickEvent(item, r.Next(0, 11));
    }
}

private void SubscribeToClickEvent(MenuButton mb, int i)
{
    RoutedEventHandler handler = (sender, e) => MyClickEvent(sender, e, i);
    clickHandlers.Add((mb, handler));
    mb.Click += handler;
}

private void UnsubscribeFromClickEvents()
{
    foreach (var (button, handler) in clickHandlers)
    {
        button.Click -= handler;
    }
    clickHandlers.Clear();
}
```

Comment: @Ben Edited to response to your edit of your question

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while since I worked with WPF but I'm pretty sure you can just have another method that does the opposite:

```
private void UnsubscribeToClickEvent(MenuButton mb, int i) 
{
    mb.Click -= (sender, e) => MyClickEvent(sender, e, i);
}
```

Comment: to quote on Canton7: "Doesn't work -- it instantiates a new delegate instance, which (unsurprisingly) isn't in the delegate's invocation list ".